# Как проанализировать код на наличие неиспользуемых функций?

Tags: linux, c, ld

Код написан на языке C.

Флаг `-Wall` может показать только локальные функции. Как быть с глобальными?

Какие средства анализа кода существуют? Насколько я понимаю, мы ведь это можем увидеть на этапе линовки всех объектников в один? Может это может показать линковщик?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уточню, что это для случая статического анализа кода - поиск функций, к которым по коду нет обращений. Вам может помочь утилита [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/), она так же имеет очень большой список различных проверок, кроме поиска неиспользуемых функций.

Если же хотите посмотреть какие методы вызывались в процессе выполнения, то их список может отличаться в зависимости от входных данных, для их просмотра можно использовать `valgrind`

Comment: Почему-то, cppcheck не находит неиспользуемые функции. Хотя в настройках стоит. Как Вы это делаете?